# How to get a reference to transcluded element in AngularJS component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, components, angularjs-ng-transclude

We are trying to build a component that uses transclude with several slots.

The component looks something like this:

```
import templateUrl from './pop-box.html';
import './pop-box.scss';

const PopBoxComponent = {
    bindings: {},
    transclude: {
        'trigger': 'popBoxTrigger',
    },
    templateUrl,
    controller: class PopBoxComponent {

    },
};

export default PopBoxComponent;
```

With it's html as:

```
<div class="pop-box">
    <ng-transclude ng-transclude-slot="trigger"></ng-transclude>
</div>
```

It is intended to be used as follows:

```
<ps-pop-box>
        <pop-box-trigger>
            <button type="button"class="btn btn-transparent">
                Button
            </button>
        </pop-box-trigger>
    </ps-pop-box>
```

Now, everything is rendered property. But, I need to attach an event to the transcluded button.

Is it possible an how to get an access to the transcluded element?

Maybe there is another option to attached an event to a button that calls a function inside the component.

**Some more details**

the resulting html from the above is:

```
<ng-transclude ng-transclude-slot="trigger"><pop-box-trigger class="ng-scope">
            <button type="button" data-ng-disabled="$ctrl.disabled" class="btn btn-transparent ng-binding">
                <i class="far fa-user fa-fw"></i>
                Assign
            </button>
        </pop-box-trigger></ng-transclude>
```

So, if I add an event to `<ng-transclude ng-transclude-slot="trigger" on-click="onClick()"></ng-transclude>`, it will bound to the `ng-transclude` element instead of on the button.

How can I make it set on a button?

Comment: do you need to bind an event inside your transcluded content related to the content of the component which hosts the transclusion? so in your case, do you need to add an event to the button which refers to the scope of the same `PopBoxComponent `?

Comment: I need to bind the `onClick` event on a button, to a function of `PopBoxComponent`.

Comment: why not `<ng-transclude ng-transclude-slot="trigger" ng-click="MY_FUN"></ng-transclude>`?

Comment: Added some details for that

Comment: Can I somehow avoid wrapping the button with `pop-box-trigger` element?

Comment: but I mean, let's start from a question. What you are trying to do is that, for example, I can provide as dynamic content of your transclusion also other elements, but I would like that just clicking on one of these elements, the event will be fired?

Comment: I am trying to call a function on `PopBoxComponent` by clicking on a button.

Comment: I got it. But I mean, if that transclusion element is the one responsible for that trigger (only), why can't you bind it directly as I said above? To all the transcluded container? Otherwise you can inject `$element` inside your controller and find the button inside your transclusion, but if then I provide as transclusion another element, that won't work

Comment: Right, so if I could define the button as a slot (by attribute or something), I would not need to wrap it with `pop-box-trigger`. Then that would be what I need

Comment: exactly. This is usually the best approach, to create a single transcluded element which is just responsible for that event, and bind that event directly in the transclusion in your hosting component

Comment: How do I make the button transcluded without the wrapper? Or is it not possible?